# Favorites keyboard shortcuts for Explorer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

In Windows XP, I had several folder saved as favorites in Windows Explorer, and could do Alt+A, 'letter' to quickly navigate to a favorite starting with 'letter' (for example, with a favorite named 'logs' pointing to C:\blah\blah\logs, Alt+A,L would immediately take me to the logs directory).

In Windows 7, they removed the Favorites menu bar, but added a listing in the navigation pane.
I've been trying to find a simple keyboard shortcut to quickly navigate to frequently used locations.  Alt+D,F4 is the best I've found so far, but it requires actually looking through a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding your Favorites to the Start Menu (right click Start Button > Properties > Start Menu tab > Customise).

Then you have to press WinKey, Right Arrow, F, Right Arrow, to start navigating your Favorites.

It's not ideal, but you could use some macro software, like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml), to map it to a single key combo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy for them to open in a new Explorer window then I highly recommend [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). It's very powerful but fairly easy to use.

Using a script created by AutoHotkey you can map nearly any key combination to open any program or file/folder.

For example, I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> set to open My Documents and <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open or switch to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that works for me:

1. Pin Windows Explorer to the taskbar in the left-most position.
2. Pin your favorite folders to Windows Explorer.
3. Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (or other numbers according to the location of your pinned Windows Explorer on the taskbar).
4. Press the first letter of your favorite letter followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.